# Ant Pitest Subdirectories targetClasses property

Tags: ant, pitest

My code works perfectly like this.

[image: Code]

But I want to remove "org.apache.commons.lang3.*" (Whole address) and just write * so it can get all files in the current folder and subdirectories. I wanted to make my code work on different projects and don't want to change it again and again. I want to make it universal. I just want to point to the target folder and let it get all files in the folder and subdirectories files. So far I have tried:

*( .**.* )  ( .* )  (.* / )  (.* \ )*

Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the pitest Ant plugin. The globs are matched against all classes in the classpath, so using an 'everything' glob results on all classes being instrumented.

If no glob is supplied to the pitest maven plugin, it will scan the source directories and construct a filter based on the packages found there. There is no plan to port this functionality to Ant.